# How to convert from RGB numpy array to PIL image without changing colors

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to save an RGB numpy array into a image, however, when I try to it for some reason displays it using completely different colors. Does anyone know how to avoid this?
This is the code I use:

```
tissue = np.zeros((150,150,3))
for i in range(0,150,1):
      for j in range(0,150,1):
              if self.logD[i][j]>0:
                   tissue[i,j,2]=0.8
                   tissue[i,j,1]=0.6
              if self.u[i][j]!=0:
                   tissue[i,j,0]=0.8*self.u[i][j
                   tissue[i,j,2]-=self.u[i][j]
                   tissue[i,j,1]-=0.8*self.u[i][j]
tissue[self.ablator.x-4:self.ablator.x+5,self.ablator.y-4:self.ablator.y+5,1]=1;
tissue[self.ablator.x-4:self.ablator.x+5,self.ablator.y-4:self.ablator.y+5,0]=1;
```

which results in the following image when using `plt.imshow(tissue)`

[image]

however, after trying to convert it to an image as such

```
MOV = [];
MOV2 = [];
for i in range(len(env.MOVIE_ARRAY)):
     m = (env.MOVIE_ARRAY[i]*255).astype(np.uint8);
     m = np.array(Image.fromarray(m).resize((1024,1024)));
```

The image when imshowing becomes this

[image]

Is there any way to write the array into an image without changing the colors?

Comment: I forgot to mention that after setting up tissue i do MOVIE_ARRAY.append(tissue)

Comment: Are you sure that `env.MOVIE_ARRAY[i]`'s values are all between 0 and 1 inclusive? If not you'd have to normalize the array, otherwise the conversion to `uint8` would introduce integer overflow.

Comment: please check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example your code is not complete so difficult to follow by others

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you that was it! Adding in these two lines 
'tissue = tissue/np.amax(tissue)
tissue = np.clip(tissue, 0, 1)'
fixed the issue.